# Why is the col-md-6 in my page displaying full width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-grid

Using Bootstrap 5.0.2, I have a two column grid using col-md-6 twice within a row. Yet they are taking up full width rather than half of the screen and stacking vertically. How is this the case?

See html and style shet below

```html
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="mainbox lg-mainbox-left"></div>
            </div>           
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="mainbox lg-mainbox-right"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mainbox {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: black;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top;
    
}
.lg-mainbox-left {    
    background-image: url("images/herobanner-left.png");
}
.lg-mainbox-right {    
    background-image: url("images/herobanner-right.png");
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, you're viewing this on a larger than medium breakpoint screen, right? If yes, please put up a JSFiddle, it's easier to debug.

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle, but I think this is right. I had to find two substitute images. But as you can see, the two images appear one on top of the other rathe rthan side by side.

https://jsfiddle.net/Bigyeti/48g2n1fv/4/

Comment: You'd need to actually have the html syntax and the CDNs in place for the fiddle to work. I made the change https://jsfiddle.net/029vy1mc/ . And it works as expected. I think your screen size is being the problem, try using `col-6` instead of `col-md-6`. That will make it 2 columns on every screen size. If that doesn't work either, please check your CDN imports.